# Python catching errors from package, finding out which sublibrary exception belongs in

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, try-catch

I've encountered several times now that I want to catch an exception that was raised by some library, but that it takes some time to actually find where that exception resides.

### Example

Suppose I want to read some csv-file, except the seperator can be one of 2 values. I'd use:

```
import pandas
try:
    mydf=pandas.read_csv('Somefile.csv', sep=';')
    if not someValidityChecks(mydf): raise myExc.NotValidError
except:
    mydf=pandas.read_csv('Somefile.csv', sep=',')
```

Now this code catches any and all exceptions, which is not really what I want (it's not *Zen*).

What I actually want, is to catch `NotValidError`, and the exception that is thrown by pandas if it encounters some invalid csv: `ParserError`.

But `except myExc.NotValidError, ParserError` won't work, because `ParserError` is not defined in my context. Instead, it should be `pandas.errors.ParserError`.

### The question

Is there some quick way to find out where an exception is defined?

That there is a `ParserError` that I should catch, is easy enough to find out by simply letting it be thrown, the errormessage clearly shows that. Yet to find out where that error comes from, I have to dig into the stacktrace, and look at all the imports where it could be defined.

Now `pandas` doesn't have the most complicated structure, and guessing that the error could be in `pandas.errors` isn't that hard, but it still takes some time checking. Other libraries might have defined their exceptions at some more unexpected place, or spread all around. It should be easy enough to find out what actual error (including package) was thrown, right?

### Environment

I'm working with Anaconda/Spyder 3.3.2, with Python 3.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quick way to do this is to print the module of the exception and it's qualified name:

```
try:
    # thing that generates exception
    raise pd.errors.ParserError
except Exception as e:
    print(type(e).__module__, type(e).__qualname__)

pandas.errors ParserError
```